# Customized Regex replace pattern

Tags: c#, regex

On my application, I must parse a file and replace some strings.

```
1 not intressting "some string with " " !"
2 not intressting "some string" ; "commentar"
3 not intressting ;"no string to replace"
```

For the result, i expect the whole string from the first to the last quote of one line. The whole string behind an semicolon to the end of line would be ignored.

The result whitout the first and last qoutes.

```
1 "some string with " " !"
2 "some string"
3 no match
```

My regex pattern work for all strings in quotes, but how do I implement the semicolon selection?

```
(?<=^.*?\")(.*)(?=\".*?$)
```

---

Edit

```
(?<=^[^;]*?\")(.*)(?=\".*?$)
```

This regex would find all strings between the first and last quotes expect if leading a semicolon. But how i found semicolon between?

```
not intressting "some text" ;comment "not intressting"
```

matchs

```
'some text'
```

Comment: For `80023 "some string ; commentar"` and `80024 "some string with "  !"`, what is your expected result?

Comment: So what is your expected output from the 2 examples I have given?

Comment: @San Do you want that the solution matches `80023 "some string ; commentar"` or treat it as `no match`?

Comment: The result would be: 'some string ; commentar' and 'some string with " !' without quots

Comment: @San I updated my answer, for what I tested, it returns expected results, can you take a look at it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Assumption

A match is defined as a sequence:

- Starting from the first `"` in the input string. Let us call this the 1st `"` or the opening `"`.
- There is no `;` before the opening `"`
- `;` is allowed in the sequence, if the last `"` in the sequence is odd, counting from the 1st `"`.
- `;` is not allowed in the sequence, if the last `"` in the sequence is even, counting from the 1st `"`.
- Ends with the furthest `"` that satisfies the conditions above.

#### Solution

Find the *first* match with this regex (raw form):

```
^(?>[^;"]*)"((?>(?>"[^";]*(?="[^"]*$)|"[^";]*"|[^"]*)+))"
```

In C# string literal:

```
"^(?>[^;\"]*)\"((?>(?>\"[^\";]*(?=\"[^\"]*$)|\"[^\";]*\"|[^\"]*)+))\""
```

The result will be in the first capturing group.

#### Explanation

Syntax explanation:

- `(?>pattern)` is non-backtracking/possessive sub-expression. It prevents the engine from backtracking. This is a form of optimization.
- `(?=pattern)` is zero-width positive look-ahead. It checks that the string ahead conforms to the `pattern` without consuming the text.
- `|` is alternation. The thing I want to note here is that regex-directed engine will check each rule from left to right, and will not consider other rules if a match is found. That means the order matters in determining the matches.
- I assume you are familiar with the rest, since they are quite basic.

For the sake of explanation, I will use the raw regex, with the non-backtracking optimization removed:

```
^[^;"]*"((?:"[^";]*(?="[^"]*$)|"[^";]*"|[^"]*)+)"
```

Due to the requirement "first and last quote in a line", there is at most 1 match per line.

By doing some analysis on the requirement, we know that the text *before* the interested portion should not contain `;` (part of the requirement) or `"` (otherwise, the quote will not be the first). Therefore, we can write `^[^;"]*` to anchor the match from the start of the string and match everything up until the first quote `"`.

This is the quoted string part, broken up for ease of explanation:

```
"
(
(?:
"[^";]*(?="[^"]*$)
|
"[^";]*"
|
[^"]*
)+
)
"
```

Let us focus on these 3 fragments, and I will start explaining from bottom-up:

```
"[^";]*(?="[^"]*$)
"[^";]*"
[^"]*
```

For all cases here, the last quote we encountered is always an odd quote.

- `[^"]*`: The last quote is ensured to be odd quote, so we can have anything including `;`, but except for `"`.
- `"[^";]*"`: The last quote is odd quote, and after this is also odd quote. This part deals with the portion after an even quote, where `;` is disallowed.
- `"[^";]*(?="[^"]*$)`: This is the tricky part, which deals with the case where the string has an odd number of quotes (>= 3). I made sure that after the even quote, there is no `;` and followed by the last quote `"` in the string. *"Followed by the last quote `"` in the string"* is achieved with the look-ahead `(?="[^"]*$)`.

The fragment `"[^";]*(?="[^"]*$)` must be placed in front of `"[^";]*"` to avoid backtracking, so that we can apply the non-backtracking optimization.

Comment: Your solution works fine, but on multiline it matchs all line until next semicolon. In my case the mach must end with the last quotes of the line!

Comment: @San: Just read the file line by line, or add `\n` into all the character classes.

Comment: ^[^;"\n]*"((?:"[^";\n]*(?="[^"\n]*$)|"[^";\n]*"|[^"\n]*)+)" works perfect, thanks

Comment: @San: Please use the one in the Solution section. The others are for explanation only.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"Data.txt");
        string[] lines2 = lines
            .Select(line => Regex.Match(line, @"(?<!;)""((.(?!;\s*""))*)""", RegexOptions.None).Groups[1].Value)
            .Select(line => line.Length > 0 ? line : "no match")
            .ToArray();
```

This regex could be interpreted as: *take text that starts with quotes but is not immediately preceded by semi-colon and is not followed by pattern semicolon-blank space(s)-quote and ends with quotes*.